# Can Resque run jobs in parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

Can Resque run a number of similar jobs all in parallel? If so, how would you set up workers to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a `COUNT` option to the rake task, you can run multiple workers:

```
COUNT=5 QUEUE=* rake resque:workers
```

In production, you could use something like `God` to keep your processes running. The Resque project has a [sample configuration script](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/examples/god/resque.god) which allows for multiple workers.

Comment: that's it? do I need to do anything extra when enqueuing the jobs or will Resque automatically delegate each job to a different worker? also do I NEED to use `God` to manage these parallel jobs or is it something extra?

Comment: `God` is just a way to keep your processes running in production; definitely not **required**. The nature of a queue is that whenever a new job is added, the next available worker will take it. So if you have 5 workers and 5 jobs, each worker will run one job (this is a gross generalization, though -- I'm not familiar with the internals of Resque to know how they specifically handle this -- for example, if the first worker finishes its job before the 5th job is assigned, the first worker may get it instead of the last worker).

Comment: cool, thanks. So if i'm going to be having lots and lots of similar jobs running at one time (I might need to process 1000 jobs at once), should I just start up a huge number of workers? or is there a better strategy to this?

Comment: "So if you have 5 workers and 5 jobs, each worker will run one job", but not in parallel, one after another

Comment: @Luccas Is that correct? If you got 5 jobs, each worker will run 1 in parallel, no?

Comment: This should be only run in dev mode. The rake task itself says so https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/tasks.rb#L23

Answer (score 4):

I'd take a look at the [Resque Pool gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/resque-pool), it can make it really easy to set up multiple workers for different queues.  Then you can group similar tasks by queue.

If you aren't already using something for process monitoring, resque-pool can help you manage your works via a single deamon.  It also gives you a few ways to be able to monitor what is going on with your workers.  Also it lets you easily change how many workers are running for each queue through a simple yaml file.

Comment: how is this any different/better than Dylan's solution?

Comment: resque-pool has a master daemon that constantly ensures you have your configured number of workers running.  While monit or god could do this as well, the resque-pool daemon is what loads your environment and then forks out the parent worker processes.  This means if you a CoW-friendly Ruby (e.g., REE) you'll see a pretty substantial RAM savings because replacing that process will still benefit from shared memory.  A process restarted via monit or god will have a complete in-memory copy of the bootstrapped environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you monitoring with monit be careful have one pid file per worker

```
#!/bin/sh
cd <path of app>/current/
for i in 3; 
do
    VVERBOSE=1 PIDFILE=<path of app>/shared/pids/resque_$i.pid RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=name_of_queue bundle exec rake environment resque:work > <path of app>/shared/log/resque_$i.log
done
```